# Confusing complete in xml_parse_into_struct

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

When feeding xml_parse_into_struct with the following string, the "test" is marked as complete. To me, it's not and the glitch causes trouble.

Is it being parsed correctly? Any options that can be set to prevent "test" to collapse into complete?

```
<?php
$s = 
'<xml>
  <test>
I feel
incomplete
  </test>
</xml>';
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p,$s,$vals,$index);
header('content-type:text/plain');
print_r($vals);
//output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => XML
            [type] => open
            [level] => 1
            [value] => 

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => TEST
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 2
            [value] => 
I feel
incomplete

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag] => XML
            [value] => 

            [type] => cdata
            [level] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tag] => XML
            [type] => close
            [level] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Don't use that old sax like API. It is here for backwards compatibility but using DOM, XMLReader or SimpleXML is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. The tag is complete because it contains all the data and got closed and does not have any tags inside.